# How to change the glassy look in GTK3 theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3, transparency

I am wondering how can I change the glass color (transparency) in GTK3? For example, if one hits the hot-spot corner (top-left) and you go to the applications display, there is a layer of glassy sheet. How can I make that brighter because, now, I have black icons?

Answer (score 0):

I think this cannot be changed easily, Since this is the default gtk3 theme for gnome-shell (name is Adwaita). But you can use other gnome-shell themes.

1. First Install the **gnome-tweak-tool** by typing this in terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.
2. Then you need to install **gnome-shell-extensions** to be able to use custom theme. 
   command is : `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions`
3. Then add this PPA to use more gnome-shell themes

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/themes`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   then you can install other gnome-shell themes. A brighter theme is Zukitwo.

   You can install that by
   `sudo apt-get install zukitwo-colors-theme`.

Here is the description of the theme quoted:

> This package provides Zukitwo Colors theme pack which provides GTK2, GTK3 and GNOME Shell themes in all 7 colours from Shiki-Colors (Brave, Dust, Human, Illustrious, Noble, Wine and Wise), as well as a colour-neutral GNOME Shell theme (Zukitwo-Colors) and Metacity/Mutter themes for Dust (Zukitwo-Dust) and the rest (Zukitwo-Colors). (Zukitwo-Dust has a separate Metacity/Mutter theme as part of its colour-scheme.).

Then use **gnome-tweak-tool** to enable **User theme extension**. Then quit. Again start gnome-tweak-tool and select the theme you want from **Shell Themes** menu.

Hope this will helps.